# Choosing Port Numbers for Hadoop Damenons

Tags: hadoop, port, cluster-computing

I am new to Hadoop and have been looking online for references to set up a multi-node cluster. After referring to a number of different sites and the official documentation (which was too complicated for a novice such as myself) I have been using [this blog](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) as a guide.

However, I just can not understand how the Port Numbers are decided in the configuration files? I mean I refereed "Haoop In Action", the previous link and other sites and everyone seems to be using different values for the datanode, jobtracker etc.

I referred the Web UIs for the Common User from the official documentation and found this:

The default Hadoop ports are as follows:

```
Daemon  Default Port    Configuration Parameter
HDFS    Namenode    50070   dfs.http.address
Datanodes   50075   dfs.datanode.http.address
Secondarynamenode   50090   dfs.secondary.http.address
Backup/Checkpoint node? 50105   dfs.backup.http.address
MR  Jobracker   50030   mapred.job.tracker.http.address
Tasktrackers    50060   mapred.task.tracker.http.address
```

However, I have come across values such as 9000 for fs.default.name and even 54310 for the same thing. Is this even correct? Can any value be used? Please I need help on this at the earliest. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The default configuration properties are specified in the [core-default](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/core-default.html), [hdfs-default](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/hdfs-default.html) and [mapred-default](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred-default.html). The default port numbers can be changed, but the appropriate property has to be changed in the configuration files.

Comment: yes but are there specific port numbers for every version of hadoop? If yes, how can I find the appropriate port numbers?

Comment: Usually the port number remains the same across release, the documentation has to be checked for the default port numbers. In the response to the query the port numbers for 1.0.4 have been given, similarly check the documentation for the appropriate release.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Find Services and their respective Port Number:**

*NameNode* : **50070**

*DataNode* : **50075**

*Secondary NameNode* : **50070**

*Job Tracker* : **50030**

*Secondary NameNode* : **50090**

*Task Tracker* : **50030**

*Backup/Checkpoint Node* : **50105**

*Oozie* : **11000**

*Yarn Resource Manager* : **8088**

*Yarn Node Manager* : **8042**

*HUE* : **8888**

*HBase Region Server* : **60030**

*HBase Master* : **60010**

*Spark History Server* : **18088**